# How to simplify sorting in Primefaces p:dataTable component. Unexpected sorting icons founded

Tags: primefaces

I want to incorporate simple sorting to datatable in Primefaces.

My code is:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="data" value="#{dataView.avaliableData}"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             paginator="true" rows="10" sortMode="simple" paginatorPosition="bottom"> 
    <p:column headerText="#{msg.id}"  sortBy="#{data.id}">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{msg.name}"  sortBy="#{data.name}">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{msg.entity}" sortBy="#{data.entity}">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.entity}" />
    </p:column>              
    <p:column headerText="#{msg.date}" sortBy="#{data.date}">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.date}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

But the result is so confusing. This picture illustrates it (I don't have enough reputation to post it here directly).

[Click here for viewing the datatable anomaly example](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2qutann.jpg)

Why do I see several sorting items? I just want to see only an icon which sorts in ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was caused by the misapplication of the stylesheet incorporating background icon.

I gather that it was due to the version of Primefaces. I have overwritten the

> .ui.datatable .ui-sortable-column-icon

entry in my stylesheet and the strange icons has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You just remove `sortMode = "simple"` and you will see only one sort `icon` and to show the `paginator` only it exceeds the number of rows use this.

```
paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
```

in `dataTable` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the second recommendation, very useful. But deleting the sortMode is not the solution for the issue. Multiple icons still alive.